# Properly animate multiple elements with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Probably I didn't choose the best title for my question, sorry for that.

I'm pretty new with jQuery, hence with animations.
I'm just experimenting with It, but now I have a problem.

The script works like I want, but It seems a bit "buggy", **I bet my code isn't optimized**, at all... Plus I may be using a wrong way to achieve what I want.

One button is triggering the script (Its not supposed to be like that at the end, but momentarily I'm using this button to trigger the script), it works like a "toggle" and every time I click on "Show", a bunch of HTML is shown and two animations run:

```
 $(".achievement_container").hide(300).show(); //shows the whole container
 $(".glow").fadeIn(100).fadeOut(800); // First "brightening" effect
```

This one shows the whole "frame", while another animation runs for a lighting effect:

```
$(".ach_hover").css("left", "0px").css("opacity", "1").animate({
            left: "252px",
            opacity: "0"
        }, 1100);
```

You can see a "working" example here:

### http://jsfiddle.net/Frondor/6EA6W/

My problem appear *after I click the "Show" button many times*, the `$(".ach_hover")` animation start to fail and it doesn't appear, at all...
I'm not satisfied with the way I wrote this last animation, at least I think there might be a better and "standard" way to achieve this.

So I would really appreciate any suggestion from jQuery experts to "**optimize**" my script, and avoid any buggy behavior on it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using `.stop()` Like this http://jsfiddle.net/6EA6W/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using jQuery **[`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)**

> Stop the currently-running animation on the matched elements.

```
$(".ach_hover")
 .css({
        "left": "0px",
        "opacity": "1"
 })
 .stop()
 .animate({
        left: "252px",
        opacity: "0"
}, 1100);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6EA6W/1/)**

Comment: Can you explain me a bit about how .stop() and my script works? So I learn a bit :D AND, regarding to the `$(".ach_hover")` animation... What do you say about it? Is there any way to write it "better" or it's actually ok?

Comment: When .stop() is called on an element, the currently-running animation (if any) is stopped. So your `.animate()` does not start before the previous animation is stopped

Comment: For your second question, you can combine the css properties, see updated answer